# Apache htdocs access restricted

Tags: html, windows, apache, server, webserver

I'm running an Apache web server 2.2 inside a Windows 10 VM. Whenever I try to edit the index.html file in the htdocs directory, I get an error that prevents me from saving any new documents to the folder. Is there any way to circumvent this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brendan

I had the same problem as you and I figured out a way. You need to edit the file as administrator.

Here is the way I did it:

1. Open CMD as administrator.
2. Run the command `net user`.
3. Run the command`net user administrator /active:yes`.
4. Run `net user administrator *`.
5. Enter your new password.
6. Click the windows tab and click on your current user account.
7. Switch over to the newly created Admin account.
8. Go to the file you want to edit.
9. Edit Away, my friend!

Comment: Thanks for the help, Srivishnu!

Comment: You're so Welcome